# Probability that a 3-digit randomly chosen number is divisible by 5

Tags: probability

$$\text{Set}\; = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$$

Find the probability that a three digit number which does not have the digit $0$ chosen  at the far left and is chosen at random from the set, is NOT a multiple of 5.

$$P(\text{NOT A multiple of 5}) = \dfrac{6\cdot 7 \cdot 5}{6\cdot 7\cdot 7} = \dfrac{210}{294} = \frac{5}{7}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is just fine.

Comment: IF you sample with replacement, yes

Answer (score 4):

It is perfectly correct, yes. Well done.

But in any "submitted" answer you might give, e.g., in an assignment or on a test, it would also be good to include a few words about **how** you arrived at your answer, or **why** you believe it is the answer. Oftentimes, the calculations "speak for themselves," and the reasoning is easily followed, but not always.

Comment: MethodMan: any chance you might be thinking of accepting this answer? ;-)